# Java : how to create a directory inside under usr in linux from a java app?

Tags: java, directory

I'm trying to create a folder under /usr in linux from a java program. Here's what I've done. I understand that I lack the permission to do so under /usr but what do I need to add?

```
public void createDirectory (String path)
{
    File directory = new File(path);
    if (!directory.exists()) {
        if (!directory.mkdirs()) {
            System.out.println("couldn't create file");
        }
    }
}
```

Here the sysout statement gets printed. what needs to be done here? Would greatly appreciate your help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have permission to create directories under `/usr`? Generally its not a good idea for your program to be writing to this location

Comment: Stupid me, I thought the permissions were already set, but it wasn't. I had set the permission now, it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mkdirs()` is used in case you want to create nested folders.

Try with `mkdir()` instead:

```
public void createDirectory (String path)
{
    File directory = new File(path);
    if (!directory.exists()) {
        if (!directory.mkdir()) {
            System.out.println("couldn't create file");
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that you must provide the full path in order to make it work. Also as @Reimeus mentioned in the comment above, is not a good idea to write or create anything at that level, I would suggest to create it under /home/your_user/

Comment: Besides, I think the application user doesn't have proper permission to create a directory. For example, if you compile and run your java file in your terminal, please make sure you change the user as root by using "sudo su" command. Meanwhile, somehow you have to figure out how to give root permission to your IDE in case if you run the java file from an IDE.

Comment: Yep got it, I didn't have the permissions before and now it just works fine.